# Get time from external device for android tv

Tags: android, android-tv

I have an application which is being deployed in android tv boxes, but as the tv boxes does not have any inbuilt flash to store the date, it uses the network to get the date from NTP.

So, in case network inavailability i am not able to fetch the correct time. Is there any device or way to get the current time which does not depend on the network connectivity.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: get a time from the server through the web services

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to find correct time if device is not connected to any network, that's as same as mobile, with the only exception that mobile phones update themselves from Network Providers. I'll keep digging it and if found something will tell you.

Comment: if there is once internet connect to your app then you can get date and time.then by `handler ` yo can code to update time.